# Xamarin binding Reference is it needed for every element?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code in my application:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="pfs" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

   <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,0,20,0" Orientation="Horizontal"
      HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
      <Label x:Name="scoreCountLabel" 
        TextColor="{Binding BindingContext.TickMarkColor, Source={Reference pfs}}"/>
   </StackLayout>
```

I am trying to understand how the TextColor is set. Can someone explain to me why the developer has set the Source={Reference pfs}

Why is this needed as it's already inside a StackLayout with the name of pfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely unnecessary from what I can tell. BindingContext is inherited by all subviews, so referencing the parent view's BindingContext is redundant.

```
TextColor="{Binding TickMarkColor}"/>
```

Done.